# PDE method of characteristics question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image: Pde question, hopefully attached]

I would really appreciate some help with this question. So far I've got: $dx/1 = dy/(e^{-x}-y)=d(\theta)/(2x)$. (Label the equations 1, 2, 3).

Solving $1$ and $3$ is easy: $x^{2}= \theta$ + constant $(A)$

But with whichever pair I choose to solve next, it becomes incredibly messy (and I can't find a place to sub in $(A)$ so that one of the constants disappears.  I'm guessing I'm making a simple mistake, because my answer is too messy to be right.

Please help....

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/zGL3t.png

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have already solved your problem, but here are step-by-step solution:

1) From Lagrange-Charpit identities we have:

$$ \frac{dx}{1} = \frac{dy}{e^{-x} - y} = \frac{d\phi}{2x}, $$

2) then, from (1) and (3), it yields: $\phi = x^2 + K$, where $K$ is a constant of integration.

3) From (1) and (2) you can obtain a functional relation between $x$ and $y$ through the characteristics. This is:

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} + y = e^{-x},$$

which is a first order ODE, whose solution can be readily obtained in terms of an integrating factor (or by solving the homogeneous equation firstly and obtaining a particular solution afterwards):

$$y = x e^{-x} + M e^{-x}, $$

being $M$ another constant of integration.

4) Set $K = K(M)$, where $M$ can be obtained from the step (3): $M = y e^{x} - x$, since $e^{-x} \neq 0$, unless, maybe, in $x \to \infty$.

5) Step 4 allows you to compute the solution in terms of $K$ as follows:

$$\phi(x,y) = x^2 + K(y e^x - x),$$ being $K$ an arbitrary function of its arguments. You can check that this is a solution of the original PDE (it satisfies the PDE).

6) Satisfy the condition $\phi = x^3$, $y=0$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$. From (5):

$$x^3 = x^2 + K(-x) \Rightarrow K(s) = s^2(1-s), \quad s \equiv -x,$$

so, finally:

$$\phi(x,y) = x^2 + (ye^x - x)^2 (1-y e^x + x)$$

I hope this is useful to you. Cheers!